# Core Data NSManagedObjectContext save never returns when called from a background queue

Tags: multithreading, swift, core-data, nsoperationqueue

My app (unit test) is stalling when I call `save()` in an `NSManagedObjectContext`'s private queue, originating from a separate background queue. It is a normal Core Data stack (with an in-memory persistent store for the unit tests).

Isn't the whole point of a private-queue context that you shouldn't be concerned about what queue an operation comes from? How should I resolve this?

I haven't been able to reproduce it in isolation, but here's a rough idea of my setup (pseudo-Swift, condensing calls across multiple classes):

```
let store = inMemoryStoreCoordinator()

let mainContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
mainContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = store

let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
childContext.parentContext = mainContext

let q = NSOperationQueue()
let group = dispatch_group_create()

q.addOperationWithBlock {
    dispatch_group_enter(group)
    childContext.performBlock {
        try! childContext.save()
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }
}

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

Comment: Does adding a persistent store coordinator improve things?

Comment: @pbasdf No, it doesn't. I updated the question to mention that my actual code experiencing the issue has a PSC.

Comment: I tried this a few times, and sometimes I get just "a"; sometimes "a" and "b".  I think it might just be a timing issue - the foreground processing completes before the async.  If you add some processing after the dispatch_async, you see both "a" and "b".

Comment: @pbasdf Interesting, so that explains why the playground is showing that behavior. Add `XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true` and it works. I'll need to come up with a better test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what's causing the deadlock. I'm using a dispatch group to lock the main thread, and apparently when the child context goes to save to its parent context (a Main Queue context), that's causing the deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for a couple of reasons, but none that we can deduce from the provided code. Luckily, should be fairly easy to debug, just pause the debugger after the deadlock (most probably) occurs and see what's waiting for what. It could be a context merging deadlock, I'd put my money on that.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that and the debugger won't pause. Once it gets into that state I have to stop the process.

Comment: Ah, saw your update. Ignorre my answer, leaving it here for posterity

Comment: I set a breakpoint at the `try save()` line, then step over. After a few seconds (it's obviously deadlocked at that point, as there's no data to save), I click the Pause button (or hit ^⌘Y), which has no effect.

Comment: I need to update the question, because my playground example doesn't actually demonstrate the issue anymore. I found out it wasn't waiting for the async call to complete.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I figured it out. It's pretty bad that the pause didn't work. I guess that happens when there's a deadlock on the main thread?